# java, try block produces an error while manipulating a variable coming from the scope above try's scope

Tags: java, variables, scope, try-catch

I have declared a BufferedImage outside the try block, and initialize it inside it. but this doesn't seem to work because the compiler is considering that the local variable i isn't accessible in the try block and it shows the following error line 8

```
    The local variable i may not have been initialized
```

I wonder why this happened and if there is a way to circumvent this?

I may have included all the code that is under the catch block in the try block but I want to know how scopes are handled in that case shown here,
here is the code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage i;
    try {
        i=ImageIO.read(new File("forest.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel p=new DrawImage().new panel(i);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
    
}
```

by the way, I have tried the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945249/java-scope-try-catch) and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you want to get rid of that message, then initialize the variable like: ``BufferedImage i = null;``.

Comment: you are right it works, thanks @NomadMaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized the variable, `i` and therefore you are getting this error.

Replace

```
BufferedImage i;
```

with

```
BufferedImage i = null;// Or any other value as per your business requirement
```

### Why is this initialization required?

Compiler doesn't know what value `ImageIO.read(new File("forest.jpg"))` will return and therefore you must assign some initial value to `i` to which you are assigning `ImageIO.read(new File("forest.jpg"))`.

Comment: You are most welcome. As I have already explained in the answer, the compiler doesn't know what value `ImageIO.read(new File("forest.jpg"))` will return and therefore you must assign some initial value to `i`. This is the requirement by the compiler and we have to conform to it. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: your solution works, but I still not understand why  ' BufferedImage i = null; '  is necessary, because JDK initializes every declared variable before it is initialized with null implicitly?

Comment: @MohammedNAIMI - You are most welcome. I also recommend you go through the section, [Default Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).